# SBT : Running Spark job on remote cluster from sbt

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I have a spark-job (lets call it wordcount) written in Scala, which I am able to run in following manners

- Run on a local spark instance from within sbt

  > sbt>  runMain WordCount [InputFile]  [Otuputdir] local[*]
- Run on a remote spark cluster spark-submit the jar

  > sbt>  package
  >
  > $> spark-submit --master spark://192.168.1.1:7077  --class  WordCount target/scala-2.10/wordcount_2.10-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar   [InputFile]  [Otuputdir]

Code :

```
// get arguments
val inputFile = args(0)
val outputDir = args(1)
// if 3rd argument defined then use it
val conf = if ( args.length == 3 )  new SparkConf().setAppName("WordCount").setMaster(args(2)) else  new SparkConf().setAppName("WordCount") 
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

How can I run this job on remote spark cluster from SBT ?

Answer (score 3):

There is a sbt plugin for spark-submit. https://github.com/saurfang/sbt-spark-submit